# How to view latest submissions to Chrome WebStore?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Am I missing something or there is no way to browse the latest submissions to the Chrome WebStore? How users are supposed to find new extensions, apps, themes then? Old Extension Gallery had "Most recent" section, and WebStore does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to browse latest submissions to WebStore. As for new extensions, you can browse through [this list](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/list/newest).